# How to enable mod_security rule for a file and a folder only

Tags: apache, mod-security2

Disabling OWASP SQL_ATTACK CRS RULE, i used this

```
# ModSecurity Rule Exclusion: 942100 SQL Injection Detected via libinjection
   SecRuleRemoveByTag WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION 
#Disabled Generally
```

And, i only want it to be enabled on only a folder ( /Pay ) and a file ( /pay.php )

```
#I know i can do something with this, but don't know what. 
<LocationMatch "^/pay">
</LocationMatch>
```

Can someone enlighten me on using mod_security on Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work to disable that category of rules ONLY for requests that don't start with Pay or pay:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "!^/[Pp]ay" "id:1000,phase:2,ctl:ruleRemoveByTag=WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"
```

I prefer to write a new, override rule using ModSecurity's ctl method rather than using Apache's Location blocks as Location does not work for any phase 1 rules (though I'm pretty sure all SQL Injection rules are phase 2 so that could have been used in this case).

Comment: Yes. So it's only enabled for both of them. Which is what you asked for?